# Significados de "ay ay" en México

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico

¿Cuáles son los significados de "ay ay" en México?, por ejemplo:

> A: Me compré un carro nuevo, mira.
>   B: Ay (sí), ay (sí).

Para este caso, generalmente usan esta imagen en las redes sociales:
[image: ay ay]

Otro ejemplo pero con otro uso es en la canción de "**[Cielito lindo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cielito_lindo)**":

> Ay, ay, ay, ay,
>   Canta y no llores

También otro es el que comenta @FrankComputer de la serie Power Rangers del [robot Alpha 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrzS_LEodRY)

Comment: El robot Alpha 5 de los Power Rangers es el que mejor sabe el significado.

Comment: El *ay si* de las redes sociales es parodia de [Neil DeGrasse Tyson](http://youtu.be/0h8frPlpJN0?t=1m31s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Used heavily in El Paso, Texas, USA and Ciudad Juárez, Chihuahua, Mexico, "ay ay" is the repetition of the Spanish word "ay" which is equivalent to the interjection "oh" of the English language. When "ay" is said twice, i.e. "ay ay", it functions as an expression or acknowledgement of frustration, absurdity, disdain, and other "negative" feelings.

```
- Some Mexican dude: I'm going to run for president. 
- Some Mexican chick: Ay ay.
```

[Página web de referencia: Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ay%20ay)

Aunque el ejemplo que propones se acerca a la segunda definición de la misma página web.

> Used in place of "whatever", "yeah right", "no way", or "nuh-uh"

Answer (score 1):

*Ay ay* es una expresión que se utiliza  en situaciones de asombro o cuando alguien dice algo en broma

Ejemplo de broma:

—Persona 1: acabo de descubrir que mi amigo es un illuminati.
—Persona 2: Ay ay jajaja (risitas).

Ejemplo de asombro:

—Persona 1: Me acaban de chocar.
—Persona 2: Ay ay, ¿estás  bien?

Un dato curioso es que el *ay ay* de asombro es más largo que el de broma